# Problem rooting intex y2 aqua 1gb

Tags: root-access, fastboot

I am trying to root my phone using Ubuntu.
 When I try

> adb reboot bootloader

My device boots into fastboot mode

When I try

> fastboot devices

It list my device.
But when I try

> fastboot oem unlock

It freezes with 3 dots.
Any idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not every device is rooted the fastboot way like Nexus phones do, especially when the device in question is a MediaTek one.

I did a quick search and the result checks out: you'll need MediaTek's scatter flashing tool. Read this: [LINK: XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/root-intex-aqua-y2-100-root-guide-t2960316)

I don't have the device so it's up to you to verify whether this works. Either way, do hang around XDA and other forums often for this sort of info.